# Extracting data from Table2 to TextArea of Table1

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have designed 2 tables in my aspx page. In `table1` there is  blank `TextArea`. In `table2` there are fields like `FirstName`,`LastName`,`Age`,`DOB` and these attributes are already entered in the database. I have entered corresponding symbols for these attributes (for e.g. for Firstname symbol is {F}, for last name symbol is {L} etc..).

My requirement is when i click on a field of `Table2` (for e.g. `FirstName`) it will be displayed on `TextArea` of `table1` like "Hi My Name is {F}".

Comment: Yea, right.. And where's your effort? What have you tried and what didn't work as expected? Don't expect people to do work for you.

Comment: We should rather see your efforts first. Then we can try to help to solve your problem.

Comment: I am a beginner in asp.net and am not getting an Idea to do this.As I have recently joined as Intern in 1 of IT company

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried myself  to do this program, but i did not extract the
>   symbol of the attribute in my textarea.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AITPLCP72\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Template;Integrated Security=True");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select field,Symbols from temp2", con);
            adp.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    protected void btnfirstname_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Symbol("firstname");
    }
    protected void btnlastname_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Symbol("lastname");
    }
    protected void btnage_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Symbol("age");
    }
    protected void btndob_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Symbol("dob");
    }
    protected void btnsubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = TextArea1.InnerHtml;
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:2482/Template1/Default3.aspx?text1=" + s);
    }


    public void Symbol(string s)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (row[0].ToString() == s.ToString())
            {
                string st = TextArea1.Value;
                st += row["Symbols"];
                TextArea1.Value = st;
            }
        }
    }
}
```